# Remove clonezilla pendrive during clone

Tags: clonezilla

Is it possible to load the entire system image into the `initrd`, `initramfs` or load it into memory some other way, so that the media can be removed after the initial boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `docache` parameter to kernel. Or an easy way, at boot menu select `Other modes of Clonezilla` and select `Clonezilla (To RAM...`